# Export from xen to azure

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v, xen, azure

I want to move a Ubuntu Server VM from Xen to Azure Cloud. I exported the VM to a xva format. I converted it to ovf using Citrix XenConvertor and I obtained the vhd file. In Azure I created a disk from the vhd file. Finally I created a VM using the disk but it gets stuck on running (Provisioning). Do I have to do some configurations in the VM before exporting it?